# Updating Existing Column Attributes - Laravel 5 Migration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, database-migration

## I have

a existing column called `cpe_mac`. I created it via migration like this :

```
$table->string('cpe_mac')->default(NULL)->nullable();
```

---

## I want

I want to add this `->unique()` to that column, without having to **drop it and re-add**.

---

## I've tried

```
$table->string('cpe_mac')->unique();
```

---

**Migration File**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AlterCaptivePortalTable212017 extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('captive_portals', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('cpe_mac')->unique();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('captive_portals', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('cpe_mac')->default(NULL)->nullable();
        });
    }
}
```

---

## I kept

getting

```
SQLSTATE[42701]: Duplicate column: 7 ERROR:  column "cpe_mac" of relation "captive_portals" already exists
```

Is there a way to achieve this without having to drop my existing column? I have a lot client data that can't be deleted.

Answer (score 7):

`Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('cpe_mac')->unique()->change();
});`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#changing-columns

Answer (score 5):

You need to use [`change()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#modifying-columns) method:

```
Schema::table('captive_portals', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('cpe_mac')->unique()->change();
});
```

Alternatively, you may create the index after defining the column. For example:

```
$table->unique('email');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#indexes

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and this is the solution for Laravel 5.6:

Step1: run this command: `composer require doctrine/dbal`

step2:run this command:`php artisan make:migration THE
-NAME_YOU_WANT --table=TABLENAME`

step3: in the added migration, add `$table->string('cpe_mac')->unique()->change();` in Schema::table part.

step4: run this command: `php artisan migrate`

Answer (score 0):

If the column is already defined you can use:

```
$table->unique('cpe_mac');
```